# Select the first group of consecutive child elements of given type via XPath

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I think it's best to illustrate the question with an example. Let's assume following input:

```
<div id='content'>
    <h1></h1>
    <h3></h3>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>
    <div><p>x</p></div>
    <p>d</p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p>e</p>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to select among the child elements of the root `div` element the first group (`Z`) of consecutive `p` elements, i.e., only those with content (in this particular case) `a`, `b`, and `c`. Small complication is that the first `p` element in `Z` might be preceded in the context of its parent by an arbitrary sequence of ''non-`p`'' elements, while the last `p` element of `Z` might be in similar fashion followed by arbitrary markup.

To this end, I tried to use following XPath approach (within `lxml`):

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring(r'''
    <div id='content'>
        <h1></h1>
        <h3></h3>
        <p>a</p>
        <p>b</p>
        <p>c</p>
        <div><p>x</p></div>
        <p>d</p>
        <h2></h2>
        <p>e</p>
    </div>
''')

q=r'''
    /div[@id="content"]/p[count(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::p)]) 
    =
    count(/div[@id="content"]/p[1]/preceding-sibling::*)]
'''
for el in tree.xpath(q):
    print(el.text)
```

It seems that it more or less works, although I was wondering whether there is not some more "idiomatic" solution to this problem?

Comment: this looks idiomatic w.r.t XPath